# Application icon not displayed when running from program files(x86) folder but yes otherwise

Tags: icons

I have created a win form application (Visual Studio 2008), packaged it in an installer and tried to 'install' it on my computer (essentially testing my installer). Strange thing occurs in that when I run my installed application (installer successfully installs the files) directly from its corresponding folder in `Program Files(x86)` folder the application icon is not displayed (instead some generic icon is used). However, when I take all the files from application folder `MyAppFolder` under `Program Files(x86)` and copy them over to another folder to say `C:\\MyAppFolder` then running my application will display the correct icon. Similarly, creating a shortcut of my app from `Program Files(x86)` to desktop and running the program using the shortcut displays the icon properly too. The only scenario where the icon is not there is when I click the `.exe` directly in `Program Files(x86)\\MyAppFolder`.
It wouldn't worry me too much if I could guarantee that users of my application will see the icon after creating the shortcut but I am not sure that it always will be the case. Basically I am looking to understand how this icon is located/searched for in the first place. To add for clarification, in my code  in `InitializeComponent()` I set

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon cache is out of date. Windows has cached the icon of an earlier version of your executable, and has not caught up with your latest version. You'll need to refresh the icon cache. A restart usually does the trick.

Comment: But the 'wrong' icon I see is not an icon from an earlier version of my .exe. It's a completely different icon.